# How to exclude nested class from a dependency using gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, shadowjar

could someone tell me how to exclude nested classes from a dependency or if that is even possible with gradle. This is what im basically trying to do,
my jar uses code from a dependency that is compiled into the jar on build and path is relocated that part works fine but the class that im using has several nested classes that i don't need, so im looking for a way to exclude those nested classes.

I tried doing this but it doesn't change anything i still get full class into my jar.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name = 'sonatype'
        url = 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/'
    }
    maven {
        name = 'CodeMC'
        url = 'https://repo.codemc.org/repository/maven-public/'
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile 'org.bstats:bstats-bukkit:1.7'
}

shadowJar {
    relocate 'org.bstats', 'me.lynx.libs.bstats'
    exclude 'org.bstats.bukkit.Metrics$AdvancedBarChart'
    exclude 'org.bstats.bukkit.Metrics$AdvancedPie'
    exclude 'org.bstats.bukkit.Metrics$CustomChart'
    exclude 'org.bstats.bukkit.Metrics$DrilldownPie'
    exclude 'org.bstats.bukkit.Metrics$MultiLineChart'
    exclude 'org.bstats.bukkit.Metrics$SimpleBarChart'
    exclude 'org.bstats.bukkit.Metrics$SimplePie'
    exclude 'org.bstats.bukkit.Metrics$SingleLineChart'
}

assemble.dependsOn shadowJar
```

Comment: This feels like playing with fire.  You're violating the integrity of the JAR by intentionally excluding certain class files from it; you can't *immediately* prove that those class files aren't necessary or are unneeded.

Comment: @Makoto So is this considered a bad practice and i should not try and do things like this? Also nested classes are used only if i try to create custom charts which im not trying to do, i just want the default ones thats the reason i tried to remove it so i know for sure that they are not necessary and wont be called.

Comment: You're taking what was compilation integrity and removing the shrink wrap from it.  It *might* work, but not only is there no warranty, there's no promising that removing compiled classes that aren't directly under your control from a JAR won't wind up corrupting your application, either.